# How to make the directives less verbose?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here I have a login field, a password, username and login button. As you can see it is very verbose.

```
<form name='form' novalidate ng-submit="form.$valid && submit('/login')" ng-focus="showError=false" ng-controller='loginController' >
    <h2>Login</h2>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : ((form.username.$touched || form.$submitted) && form.username.$invalid) || showError}">
        <input ng-focus="showError=false" type="email" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model='data.username' ng-disabled="loading" required>
        <span ng-show="((form.username.$touched || form.$submitted)  && form.username.$invalid) || showError" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback glyphicon-remove"></span>
        <p ng-show="(form.username.$touched || form.$submitted)  && form.username.$invalid" class="help-block text-left">Enter a valid email</p> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : ((form.password.$touched || form.$submitted)  && form.password.$invalid) || showError}">
        <input ng-focus="showError=false" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model='data.password' ng-disabled="loading" required>
        <span ng-show="( (form.password.$touched || form.$submitted)  && form.password.$invalid ) || showError" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback glyphicon-remove"></span>
        <p ng-show="(form.password.$touched || form.$submitted)  && form.password.$invalid" class="help-block text-left">Enter a password</p> 
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-disabled="loading">
     Log in</button>
</form>
```

I am repeatedly using expressions of the kind

```
((form.username.$touched || form.$submitted)  && form.username.$invalid) || showError
```

Is there a smart way to minify the amount of code in this example? Is there any best practise?

Comment: You could create a directive that wraps the functionality of each formgroup

Comment: @KevinB How would I go about doing that, since ng-show is already a directive?

Comment: @Yoshi Isn't ngMessages is useful when having several different messages? I only want to show one message.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have your Controller to take care of most of the logic in your template. 
In there you seem to have declared something like `$scope.login = function(){ ... }` which is called after you did your form validation. (just guessing).

Instead of this approach, i would try and use something like a `$scope.processForm = function(){ .. }` which is called on your submit button. This function should then call a `validate()` function which does your validation stuff, and if it succeeds your `login()` function is called.

The next step would be to implement a `service`, for example a validation service, which can be used not only by your login controller, but all controllers who care for validating (just as an example).

This will get rid of all your boolean expressions and in general a much more cleaner and better maintanable code.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but why do I want to have a validation function? The reason for using AngularJS is that I don't need that. The boolean expressions are not for validating, they are there to hide or show data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about best practise, but you could always put a function on the scope and call that instead. So, in the controller:

```
scope.showMessage = function (inputName) {
    return ((form.username.$touched || form.$submitted)  && form[inputName].$invalid) || showError;
}
```

Then call that from the markup eg:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : showMessage('username')">
```